# selecting all values in GroupBy

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a scenario wherein i have three columns in my table. ID(String),Desc (string) TerminationDate, Last Update Date(Time).
There is no primary key, so there might be multiple rows with same set of data but LastUpdate Date will always be different.
I need to write a SP wherein i need to get the latest modified result(ID,Desc, termination date). pls see the example below

```
ID    Desc    TerminationDate    LastUpdtDt
A     test     01-01-2013        01-01-2013
A     test1     01-03-2013        25-01-2013
A     test     01-01-2013        26-03-2013
B     test     01-01-2011        01-01-2013

The result i shuld get is 
A     test     01-01-2013        26-03-2013
B     test     01-01-2011        01-01-2013
```

Let me know in case you need more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  ID, [DESC], TerminationDate, LastUpdtDt
FROM
        (
            SELECT  ID, [DESC], TerminationDate, LastUpdtDt,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID 
                    ORDER BY LastUpdtDt DESC) rn
            FROM    TableName
        ) ss
WHERE   rn = 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2c028/2)

Answer (score 1):

You could return the rows with the `max(LastUpdtDt)` using a subquery:

```
select t1.id,
  t1.[desc],
  t1.terminationdate,
  t1.LastUpdtDt
from yt t1
inner join
(
  select max(LastUpdtDt) LastUpdtDt, id
  from yt
  group by id
) t2
  on t1.id = t2.id
  and t1.LastUpdtDt = t2.LastUpdtDt;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e9908/7).

Comment: Thanks bluefeet. appreciate the effort.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  ID ,
        DESC ,
        TERMINATION_DATE ,
        LAST_UPDATE
FROM    ( SELECT    ID ,
                    DESC ,
                    TERMINATION_DATE ,
                    LAST_UPDATE ,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY LAST_UPDATE DESC ) SERIAL_ORDER
          FROM      LAST_UPDATE
        ) B
WHERE   SERIAL_ORDER = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, bu this is similar to the answer posted by JW.